# Handle null in getter method in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am creating one UI which populate values from js getters. But I am getting null text in UI when the field is empty in UI.

```
@wire(..)
case;
 get contactName() {
        return `${getFieldValue(this.case.data, Contact_First_NAME)} ${getFieldValue(this.case.data, 
                  Contact_Last_Name)}`;
      }
```

HTML UI>

```
<div> {contactName} </div>
```

** this is showing below outout if suppose first name is blank in last name is "Test"
Output:  nullTest****

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
get contactName() { 
    return `${ getFieldValue(this.case.data, Contact_First_NAME) || "" } ${ getFieldValue(this.case.data,  Contact_Last_Name) || "" }`;
}
```

Comment: can u pls tell me why this has to handle explicitly?

Comment: @AMS Well, that's the way `getFieldValue` API is written. If value does not exist, `getFieldValue` returns null.

Comment: @AMS, please mark the answer as correct, if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!